# Is Redis a bottleneck in SignalR + Redis when it comes to scaling out?

Tags: redis, signalr

I'm interested in **SignalR** + **Redis** solution for implementing a server application that is scalable. And my concern is that [Redis cluster is not production ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941897/redis-cluster-production-ready) yet! So my question is:

Is Redis a bottleneck in SignalR + Redis when it comes to scaling out? If it is, is there any Linux-based solution that solves the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a single redis server you can easily handle up to 10K concurrent clients using pubsub. If you are still evaluating what to use, this should be more than you need at your current stage.

Redis cluster is supposed to be production ready by the end of the year or early 2014. You can actually download it and try it already. Lots of people are using it now and reporting the odd bug. The creator of redis is focused on making the cluster work and as of now it is very mature.

By using the proxy you could have up to 1000 nodes simultaneously, with over 10K clients on pubsub, so 10 million of concurrent users. The limit of the cluster is theoritecally of 16384 nodes, but a maximum of 1000 is recommended right now.

Unless you are of facebook scale, you can probably use redis for your case use (and even when you are twitter scale, given twitter uses redis intensively for storing all the timelines on redis)

---

I've been asked to add some references on a comment, so here you are the relevant links:

On the number of concurrent connections per redis process http://redis.io/topics/clients

On how twitter is using redis http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html

On cluster size/specs http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

Comment: Thanks for the post, it would be great if you could provide some reference for the stats you've given.

Comment: I think of using http://garantiadata.com/ with SignalR, seems like a good scalable backplane.

Comment: Mehran, I just added the relevant links you asked for to my answer. Idan, Garantiadata are amazing, also Open Redis are awesome. Just in case you didn't know, you can also use Redis now on AWS directly as a service (Not as robust for clustering as the other two)

Answer (score 2):

> Is Redis a bottleneck in SignalR + Redis when it comes to scaling out? If it is, is there any Linux-based solution that solves the problem?

I don't think so. Check the below article on how to scale out using Redis

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-redis

Comment: Thanks for the post, I've already read that and that's why I think Redis could be a bottleneck because the whole solution is relying on it while Redis itself is not scalable.

Comment: I'm searching for a solution too to bypass this redis bottleneck problem