# Redis cluster readiness

Tags: linux, redis, production-environment

Is Redis cluster ready for Production? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941897/redis-cluster-production-ready) it seems it's not nearly ready and this also seems to be the case according to their [Github issues](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues?milestone=2&state=open).

Has anyone seen this working in large cluster environment where it requires a lot of usage?

Answer (score -1):

My company is ready for product. We had tested HA, Concurrent, Load.
I get a conclusion：
Redis cluster is Concurrent, Load more than before version.

Below is our test data:

Redis-3.0.4 version load test(3M+3S)：

```
Insert      VU=20  TPS= 3270   ART=0.006
Insert      VU=60  TPS= 5890   ART=0.009
Query       VU=60  TPS= 13232  ART=0.004
Delete      VU=60  TPS= 6631   ART=0.007
Clear       VU=20  TPS= 2302   ART=0.008
```

Redis-2.6.14 version load test：

```
Insert      VU=20  TPS= 4028  ART= 0.005
Query       VU=60  TPS= 6342  ART= 0.003  
Delete      VU=60  TPS= 6631  ART=0.007
Clear
```

We can see that vitual user  cluster is more than redis-2.6.14 and get capacity also improved. Of course, the set capacity is down(need redirect).